# network project by using DEVSJAVA tool(genDevs package)

Tags: java

I have started networks project by using the DEVSJAVA tool (genDevs). I am unable to run simulation environment.

Comment: The below link could be of help, please check it. http://acims.asu.edu/software/devsjava/devsjava-3-0-readme

Comment: So, here is the user guide, I believe it would be of help. http://www.acims.arizona.edu/SOFTWARE/PDF/DJ-UserGui-97.pdf

Comment: do u have knowledge on DEVSJava tool?. Please let me know..

Comment: Am sorry, I have not used it, but I just wanted to lend you some help.

Comment: thank you for giving information..